# How to implement auto save

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that asynchronously calls a save method on the server whenever a user leaves a text box. However it's possible that the users may spend a long time in a single text box without leaving, and if their session times out then they will lose whatever they typed when they try to save. So I would also like to save periodically (maybe once a minute or so).

I'm thinking I could add an onfocus event that will save the field once a minute, but then I could use onblur to remove the event when they leave.

Side note: Each time it auto saves it restarts the session timeout. To prevent their session from going on indefinitely, I am also going to be checking for how long it's been since their last key press and will not save if it's been longer than a minute (or whatever the save interval is).

On the one hand this is starting to seem overly complicated and so I have to ask: Is there some simpler, more straightforward to accomplish this? And if there's not, then should I be very concerned about any scenarios where the onblur event doesn't get called and doesn't get to disconnect the auto save event?

Comment: I think you're making it more complicated than it needs to be by combining  binding with your auto save functionality.  I think this might become simpler if you separate those 2 concepts.

Comment: Side note, what's the point of having a session if it's not long enough to let the user type what they need to? I, for example, sometimes like to open a tab and write a few dozen lines, then have dinner and a shower, and come back two hours later to finish my text. But for your question, instead of adding and removing events handlers, just store the entire thing that was last saved. If nothing changed, don't save.

Comment: @Quantastical It's for a Performance Management application used by a large company around the world. During the busy part of the review season last year we got tons of complaints of people "losing" data. 95% of the time it was because their session had timed out or they otherwise lost connection. We suggested that we could autosave when they leave the field but they asked that it also save periodically even if they don't leave the field. If it were up to me I would say they just need to tell them to hit the dang save button more often. :)

Comment: @Siguza Managers and employees are completing reviews so sometimes they spend a long time in a text box... and they might get up to go get a cup of coffee half way through and then get distracted. So when they get back to it 2 hours later they lose the text that they had spent 30 minutes typing so far.

Comment: @Siguza And I asked my boss the same thing... if it were up to me I'd make the session last for at least two days but it's a security/legal thing so that's not an option.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid "attaching" and "detaching" events in **onfocus** and
    **onblur**:

- In **onfocus**, only save the current focused field (DOM-node) to a
  variable
- Have just one **setInterval** global timer for auto-saves, it will
  save the field value of the field from that variable

Regarding session-continuation:

- As long as field value changes, this means user changed it [unless
  your editor is VERY dynamic and does self-editing]
- So there is no need to record key presses, just keep the
  **Last_Saved_Field_Value** to prevent saving same thing twice.